# Arcanist Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: segmentation-fault, automatic-ref-counting, pcntl, arcanist

While executing

> arc diff --trace

I am getting

> **Segmentation fault: 11**

and

> **PHP Warning:  Module 'pcntl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0**

Version of PHP 5.5.30
Zend Engine v2.5.0[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things to check...

1) Does your project have a properly written `.arccofig` file? The error message seems to indicate it is having trouble finding one. Check the [documentation](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist/) to ensure everything is set up properly.

2) Assuming you installed it correctly, you may need to update Arcanist via `arc upgrade`.

3) If you continue to have a problem, you will want to [file a bug report with Phabricator.](http://secure.phabricator.com/)

Comment: Thanks Jason. I found the problem was due to pcntl.so loading. I tried upgrading arc and libphutil but still I was having the same segmentation fault. I think this was because of replacing the actual pcntl.so file of php by an another pcntl.so file of homebrew php55 installation. So I have removed the homebrew php and then the duplicate loading of pcntl.so file got avoided which didnt gave segmentation fault anymore.